# Is there a way to only download data from Firebase if the cached data is outdated?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My first big app with Firebase just launched and I'm running into a problem - I am quickly running out of download bandwidth.

I have looked into a couple of options to cache data. I want the cached data to be used only if it is current. If the data has been updated on Firebase since the cache was created, I want to re-download all of the data.

I do not want the data updated more than once in a session. So I want to remove the observer immediately after getting the new data.

I've tried two things, but I'm not entirely sure how they work.

```
FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
```

Enabling persistence is great because just the one line of code caches everything downloaded from Firebase. Even when the app is not connected to the internet, it will pull the cached data and go about business as normal.

But my question about it is: Will the cache update when the data on Firebase updates? It appears that this is not the case.

When I go in and change a value on Firebase and relaunch the app, it just gives me the cached value, not the updated value.

So then I try this:

```
ref.keepSynced(true)
```

And this seems to work. I get the updated values when I relaunch the app.

But then my question is this: Does the app download the data every time the app launches (I do NOT want this) or just when it needs to be updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get the app to do what I want, although it is admittedly probably not the most elegant way.

1.) I call `persistenceEnabled` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. This caches all data retrieved from Firebase to be used immediately the next time the app launches.

2.) I DO NOT call `keepSynced` on the database reference. Otherwise the app would download all the data every time the app loads (not what I want).

3.) If there is new data, it is handled twice - once for the cached data immediately and then once for when the observer detects the new data. After the second time handling the data, I remove the observer. I use a counter to tell whether it's the first or second time handling the data.

4.) If there is NOT new data, it is only handled once, and nothing is downloaded.

This effectively allows me to only download data if the data cached on the device is outdated. Otherwise the cached data is used.

Here is some code to demonstrate:

```
// First download is cached data, second one is updated live data if there is updated data on Firebase

    var timesDownloaded = 0

    func downloadPops(andOnCompletion completion:@escaping ()->()){

        let baseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("SomeChild")

        baseRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

                self.timesDownloaded+=1

                // Handle the data

            }

            // First download is cached data, second one is updated live data if there is updated data on Firebase

            if self.timesDownloaded > 1 {

                print("Showing updated data")

                baseRef.removeAllObservers()

            } else {

                print("Showing cached data")

            }

            completion()

        })

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your app will synchronize data from Firebase Realtime Database whenever there is an active listener at a location in the database, and only when any data under that location changes.  When you use keepSynced, you are effectively attaching a listener at location of the reference.

When your app process stops, all listeners are effectively removed.  When your app process starts again, none of the old listeners are attached again.  You have to execute code to get new listeners attached.  If you do not attach new listeners, no new data will be synchronized.  In other words, keepSynced does not establish a persistent synchronization at a location that lasts between app invocations. You have to ask for it every time.

Enabling persistence simply allows a listener to respond to cached data immediately without having to wait for data from the service.  The listener will received the cached data first, then subsequent updates after that, as long as it's still attached and the data on the service is actually changing.

Answer (score 1):

Good question! Me and my team had *tons* of problems when using `persistenceEnabled = true` in our last app (i.e., we kept receiving outdated data from the cloud). We even made a simple command line flag to disable it by *Run* session in Xcode (aka, *dirty hack*!).

A more complete solution would be using the `FIRDatabaseReference.keepSynced(_:)` API you mentioned. Looking again at the docs it seems it will work as expected:

> By calling `keepSynced(true)` on a location, the data for that location will *automatically* be downloaded and kept in sync, even when no listeners are attached for that location. Additionally, while a location is kept synced, it will not be evicted from the persistent disk cache.

But, for a large dataset, I would recommend *not* enabling this behavior on the root node -- only on a specific subtree!